# Why Cakephp validation is not working?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

i have an input box like

```
<input id="BreakdownProgName" type="text" required="required" placeholder="customer name" size="50" name="data[Breakdown][prog_name]">
```

My model validation is not working for this code but when i put in replace of above code like below-

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Breakdown.prog_name',array('label'=>false,'div'=>false,'size'=>50,'placeholder'=>"customer name",'type'=>'text')); ?>
```

That time validation is working perfectly.but i want to use first one and also want validation works perfectly with that first code.What should i do?

My controller code is

```
public function qty_breakdown1() 
    {

            $this->layout='common';

        if(empty($this->data) == false)
        {

            if($this->Breakdown->save($this->data))
            {
                //echo "This";
                $this->Session->setFlash('B Added Successfully.', 'default', array('class' => 'oMsg1 oMsgError1'));
                $this->redirect('qty_breakdown');
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $this->set('errors', $this->Breakdown->invalidFields());    
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your validation should work regardless of the view code provided that field names are correct in POST data. That's because validation works on server side.

However if you want to display validation errors you should use Cake's FormHelper to render form elements or manually check for validation errors in view file and display them from PHP code.

Edit: Please check API: [isFieldError](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-FormHelper.html#_isFieldError) - checks if field has error and
[error](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-FormHelper.html#_error) - renders formatted error message for given field.